# API data in Django listview

Tags: django, django-views, api-design

Having trouble figuring out how to add data from an API into a listview in Django. I am using django-restframework, and have an internal API for a portion of my data. Ultimately, I want to display all the information from my Freight model, into a list view. I know I have to create a context, but I'm not sure how to do that with API data. Here is my code so far:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ManifestEngineView(ListView):
    model = Freight
    template_name = 'pages/engine.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        freight_list = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/freight/').json()
        for freight in freight_list:
            print(freight['pu_customer'])
```

I can print the customer name to the console, but I can't figure out how to put it in a context I can pass to my template and use. The template should have a box with all the necessary data from the model.

UPDATED TEMPLATE CODE:

```
<div id="origin" class="fbox">
            {% for f in freight.pu_customer %}
                <span class="freight draggable">
                {{ f }}
                </span>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ManifestEngineView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        freight_list = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/freight/').json()
        for freight in freight_list:
            context['something'] = freight 
        return context
```

try this and in template

```
{% for f in something %}
{{ f }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ManifestEngineView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['frieght']={}
        freight_list = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/freight/').json()
        context['frieght']['pu_customer'] = frieght_list
        return context
```

Answer (score -1):

API's are intented to be used from templates, with Ajax, Jquery. 
In your case you cn simply use a ListView;

in views.py

```
class ManifestEngineView(ListView):
    model = Freight
    template_name = 'pages/engine.html'
    context_object_name = 'list_freights'
```

in your template

```
 {% for item in list_freights %} //what you named your context
    <tr>
        <td>{{ item.pu_customer }}</td>
</tr>
```